# How to decode a list and remove items from two lists when there is a match in both of them based on an index?

Tags: python

I have two lists which contain the following type of information.

```
List #1:
Request_List = ["1/1/1.34", "1/2/1.3.5", "1/3/1.2.3", ...same format elements]
List #2:
Reply_List = ["1/1/0", "1/3/1", "1/2/0", ...same format elements]
```

From the "Reply" list, I want to be able to compare the second item in the "#/#/#", in this case it will be 1,3,2, and so on with all the items in the Reply list and check if there is a match with the second item in "Request list". If there is a match, then I want to be able to return a new list which would contain the information of the third index in the request string appended with the third index of the matching string in the reply.

```
The result would be like the following. 
Result = ["1.34.0", "1.3.5.0", "1.2.3.1"]
```

Note that the 0 was appended to the 1.34, the 1 was appended to the 1.3.4 and the 0 was appended to the 1.2.3 from the corresponding indexes in the "Reply" list as the second index existed in the "Reply" list. The 'Reply" list could have the item anywhere placed in the list.

The code which does the problem stated above is shown below.

```
def get_list_of_error_codes(self, Reply_List , Request_List ):
        decoded_Reply_List = Reply_List .decode("utf-8")  # I am not sure if this is 
                                           the right way to decode all the elements in the list? 

        Result = [
            f"{i.split('/')[-1]}.{j.split('/')[-1]}"
            for i in Request_List 
            for j in decoded_Reply_List
            if (i.split("/")[1] == j.split("/")[1])
        ]
        return Result
```

```
res = get_list_of_error_codes(Reply_List , Request_List)
print (res) # ["1.34.0", "1.3.5.0", "1.2.3.1"]
```

Issues I am facing right now:

1. I am NOT sure if I decode the `Reply_List` correctly and in the proper manner. Can someone help me also verify this?
2. I am not sure on how to also remove the corresponding items for the `Reply_List` and `Request_List` when I find a match based on the condition `if (i.split("/")[1] == j.split("/")[1])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use list comprehension to decode the list:

`decoded_Reply_List = [li.decode(encoding='utf-8') for li in Reply_List]`

2. In this case, if you wanted to also remove items from the list while you create the new list, I would say list comprehension *isn't* the right move. Just go with the nested for loops:

```
def get_list_of_error_codes(self, Reply_List, Request_List):
    decoded_Reply_List = [li.decode(encoding='utf-8') for li in Reply_List]

    Result = []
    for i in list(Request_List):
        for j in decoded_Reply_List:
            if (i.split("/")[1] == j.split("/")[1]):
                Result.append(f"{i.split('/')[-1]}.{j.split('/')[-1]}")
                Reply_List.remove(j)
                break
        else:
            continue
        Request_List.remove(i)
    return Result

Request_List = ["1/1/1.34", "1/2/1.3.5", "1/3/1.2.3"]
Reply_List = [b"1/1/0", b"1/3/1", b"1/2/0"]
print(get_list_of_error_codes("Foo", Reply_List, Request_List))

# Output: ['1.34.0', '1.3.5.0', '1.2.3.1']
```

Some things to note: 
I added a `break` so that we don't keep looking for matches if we find one. It will only match the first pair, then move on.

In `for i in list(Request_List)`, I added the `list()` cast to effectively make a copy of the list. This allows us to remove entries from `Request_List` without disrupting the loop. I didn't do this for `for j in decoded_Reply_List` because it's already a copy of `Reply_List`. (I assumed you wanted to remove the entries from `Reply_List`)

The last is the `else: continue`. We don't want to reach `Request_List.remove(i)` if we didn't find a match. If `break` is called, `else` will not be called, which means we will reach `Request_List.remove(i)`. But if the loop completes without finding a match, the loop will then enter `else` and we will skip the removal step by calling `continue`

EDIT:

Actually, `Reply_List.remove(j)` breaks, since we've decoded `j` in this method, thus decoded `j` is not the same object as it is in `Reply_List`. Here's some revised code which will solve this issue:

```
def get_list_of_error_codes(Reply_List, Request_List):
    # decoded_Reply_List = [li.decode(encoding='utf-8') for li in Reply_List]

    Result = []
    for i in list(Request_List):
        for j in list(Reply_List):
            dj = j.decode(encoding='utf-8')
            if (i.split("/")[1] == dj.split("/")[1]):
                Result.append(f"{i.split('/')[-1]}.{dj.split('/')[-1]}")
                Reply_List.remove(j)
                break
        else:
            continue
        Request_List.remove(i)
    return Result

Request_List = ["1/1/1.34", "1/2/1.3.5", "1/3/1.2.3"]
Reply_List = [b"1/1/0", b"1/3/1", b"1/2/0"]
print("Result: ", get_list_of_error_codes(Reply_List, Request_List))
print("Reply_List: ", Reply_List)
print("Request_List: ", Request_List)

# Output:
# Result:  ['1.34.0', '1.3.5.0', '1.2.3.1']
# Reply_List:  []
# Request_List:  []
```

What I've done is that instead of creating a separate decoded list, I just decode the entries as they're looped through, and then remove the un-decoded entry from `Reply_List`. This should be a little more efficient too, since we're not looping through `Reply_List` twice now.

Comment: Thank you so much for your continual help. I will try on my side as well to resolve the EDIT u mentioned. But doesnt the decode just remove the ```b''``` field?

Comment: @LauraSmith I've added edited code. It should work now.

Comment: @LauraSmith I assume the data you're working with requires decoding. The example list I used for `Reply_List` I used `b' '` because the example will break if I used strings, since you can't decode a string. 
If `Reply_List` is simply a list of strings, you can ignore the decoding step altogether.

Comment: I am storing json replies in the list and this looks good. I will further test it but it looks good to me. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: @LauraSmith You're welcome! And if you're storing json replies, maybe you want to look into the `json` library instead. Specifically `json.loads()`. Good luck!